# Save XDocument element by element to avoid memory exceptions

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmlwriter

How to modify my class in order to build large `XML` files? I try to use `XmlTextWriter`, but I don't know how to use it with `XDocument`. I'd like to write each `newElement`, then dispose it (in order to free RAM). Is there any possibility to do that? I know that I can use `XmlTextWriter` built-in methods to do this, but I don't want to resign from using `LINQ`...

Here's my class: http://pastebin.com/p6VfpBFg

Comment: Don't pastebin your main code, post an excerpt here.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the XStreamingElement for large XML documents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx.